# ios Testing Facebook App Install Advert Before Release

Tags: ios, facebook

I have an iOS app, now I want to install facebook app install advert for growth. But before doing that, I would like to test it, to make sure it is working fine, I have already installed facebook sdk, and check basic events are reporting it in my dashboard.
Now what I want to test is to create a facebook App advert, so that when i either open in test device, or using test facebook account, it shows only there, and I can test that it opens my test app, and events are recorded properly or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you did the installation of the SDK and everything works from your side,  follow step 2 from the following documentation:
[FB Developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started)

Will appear in your dashboard once any event has raised